# Artisan attempting to alter a table it did not create when running `artisan migrate`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

On a fresh Laravel installation, I am running `php artisan migrate` and it is returning:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                          
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users (SQL: alter table "users" add column "id" integer not null primary key autoincrement)
```

It seems to be attempting to alter a table that is not, at any point being created.

I created the migrations using:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --table=users --create
```

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone come across this before? This is on Laravel 4.2.11, PHP 5.5.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your artisan command is wrong, it should be:

```
php artisan migrate:make create_users_table --create=users
```

the --table flag is for altering an existing table

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that.